# React-Leaflet duplicate map on second MapContainer

Tags: react-leaflet

I have made basic map and I'm checking possibility to pass my map details to second MapContainer when I click button. Second map has different options than first one, but I want to keep same layers seen what is on first one.

Was thinking first to loop my layers and pass them as function to second layer, but maybe someone already have some solutions for this one? Now I need to pass only WMS details, but would like to have possibility for future to pass more different kind of layers..

Checked libraries like "leaflet-clonelayer", but I have leaflet 1.9.3 in use and library is for 1.0.3

Answer (score 0):

Well made that loop for layers anyways.. Here is my code for it :)

```
export const SecondMap = ({map}) => {
const [layers, setLayers] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    if (!map) return;
    let wmsLayers = []

    for (const prop in map.target._layers) {
        if (map.target._layers[prop].wmsParams) {
            const wmsLayer = {
                url: map.target._layers[prop]._url,
                layers: map.target._layers[prop].options.layers
            }

            wmsLayers.push(wmsLayer)
        }
    }

    setLayers(wmsLayers)
}, [])

const handleWMSLayers = () => {
    return layers.map((l => {
        return <WMSTileLayer url={l.url} layers={`${l.layers}`} />
    }))
}

return (
    <div>
        <MapContainer>
            {handleWMSLayers()}
        </MapContainer>
    </div>
)}
```